# Database mapping tools for MySQL in order to help migrate from one db to another?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, data-migration

I need to migrate WordPress data from one database to another the catch is, some of the information needs to change values. For example I have a meta_key table and I need to change all values "xyz" to "abc". Are there any GUI tools or even simple php scripts that can help?

For instance a class or function that takes in an array of current values and an array of what I would like to change them into...

A GUI tool would be preferred but any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: In the time it takes you to research a GUI you could learn the SQL it would take to do this. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a GUI ([PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net)) for MySQL with great import and export options provided as standard service by most hosts with MySQL. 
There you can export any database or selected tables and then manually replace certain values (assuming that it is a short list of values you need to replace) just by using replace function of Notepad in the export file before you would import it into the other database.

For this you don't need any SQL knowledge, but you need:
1. PHPMyAdmin installed (usually provided by the hosting service)
2. Working knowledge of PHPMyAdmin export and import options (not rocket science)

Comment: I am aware of phpmyadmin. I was looking for a tool I to auto replace for me. For example a search and replace tool that can also search and replace serialized values.